# How to match set of template parameter characters

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using Visual Studio 2013 RTM.

I am trying to write a variadic template that matches one of a number of characters.  The recursive case is easy enough, but I am struggling with writing the base case.

```
template <char C, char... Cs>
auto char_match(char c) -> bool
{
    return c == C || char_match<Cs...>(c);
}
```

I tried the following as the base case, but it didn't work.  I know that you can do this with class templates, and I was pretty certain that you can't do it with function templates.

```
template <>
auto char_match(char c) -> bool
{
    return false;
}
```

error C2912 : explicit specialization of 'bool char_match(char)' is not a specialization of a function template

I also tried using std::enable_if on the return type, but Microsoft doesn't like it.

```
template <char C, char... Cs>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Cs) != 0, bool>::type char_match(char c)
{
    return c == C || char_match<Cs...>(c);
}

template <char C, char... Cs>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Cs) == 0, bool>::type char_match(char c)
{
    return c == C;
}
```

error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if'

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case, there is no reason for recursion, just use

```
template< char... Cs >
bool char_match( char c )
{
    constexpr const std::array< char, sizeof...( Cs ) > a {{ Cs... }};
    return std::find_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
                        [c](char x){return x==c;}) != std::end(a);
}
```

Not sure if VC++ will accept the code, but GCC and Clang do.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d58024eb08eaba20)

Comment: VC++ doesn't support `constexpr`.  Other than that it works perfectly.  I also replaced `std::find_if` with `std::find`.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't anything *more specialized* about your "specialization" than the main template, so that doesn't work. I think the easiest solution would be to use a class template:

```
template <char ...> struct char_match_impl;

template <> struct char_match_impl<>
{
    static bool go(char) { return false; }
};

template <char C, char ...Cs> struct char_match_impl<C, Cs...>
{
    static bool go(char c) { return c == C || char_match_impl<Cs...>::go(c); }
};

template <char ...Cs>
bool char_match(char c)
{ return char_match_impl<Cs...>::go(c); }
```